# Sammasam Buddha's Sila, was it the best Sila?

Tags: theravada, buddha, sila, comparison

Buddha said Sariputra "*My Sila is the best/incomparable*". But people at the time of Buddha donated flowers, perfumes and jewelries to Buddha (Need citations in Pali Canon and Pitaka). The monk/num's Sila are 227 and more and monks do not allowed to get/use flowers, perfumes and jewelries, etc. How the Sila of Buddha was superior to monks' Sila whilst the latter seems more restricted than the former? Is there any more facts that I was missing to know about Sammasam Buddha's Sila?

Answer (score 2):

The Sila becomes higher depending on your knowledge of the virtues/benefits of it.
The Sila becomes higher depending on how focused you are when you are keeping them.
In other words, Sila becomes higher depending on your Samadhi & Panna.
That's why the Sila of the Buddha is higher than anyone else's.

The Lord did not use the flowers offered to him.Offering flowers is merely a way of people showing reverence to the Buddha. Perfumes are not offered. Perfumes would have been sprayed by the people when preparing places for the Buddha to stay. It is the same with jewellery.

Answer (score 1):

**Buddhas sila is the best sila**

Monks were not allowed to use those fancy things because that would distract them from going in the path to nirvana.

When someone achieved nirvana, there is no person anymore , thus there is no rules or regulations. They just exist , with the best sila in the world. Because they have stopped their desires. There's nothing else they have to do . Nothing will change their state of mind . So their sila is incomparable.